# Changes in windows 7 do not save to hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, memory, bsod, taskbar

This is kind of weird behavior: I pin an application to my taskbar. About 5 minutes later I get a bsod. When I reboot, the icon that I pinned to the taskbar is unpinned. Do these changes - to the taskbar - get saved into memory and then upon shutdown get written to the drive?

Comment: I find it interesting that your question is about pinning items to the taskbar, not the BSOD.... :)

Comment: Came here to say exactly that ^

Comment: Just curious: what does the BSoD say?

Comment: the bsod is not reproducible, it was random, so I do not know., my question is mainly about whether changes in windows 7 are saved to memory then written to the disk after a while, or written to disk directly.

Comment: Look in your application event log (or maybe system event log) to find the details of the BSOD. Meanwhile, pin your program to the task bar and then log out, and back in. That should cause it to persist.

Comment: So the original pinning is just stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

It is, as far as I know, quite normal for Windows to 'lose' the settings upon an unexpected reboot or shutdown. The same would happen if you run a 'Force shutdown' command.

The next time you boot up your Windows PC, try just moving an icon and then running the following command: `shutdown -r -f -t 0` (the command explained: "shutdown" tells the PC it is about shutting down, th "-r" parameter, that it is a reboot-shutdown, the "-f"-parameter to force Windows down (hence the 'Force shutdown') and the "-t 0" is the "how much time"-parameter - "-t 0"-tells it to commence the shutdown immediately).
When the PC has rebooted, is the icon still there, or has it in fact been moved back? It should have been moved back.

Now move the icon again, but this time reboot by pressing "Start" and selecting "reboot" from the 'shutdown'-selection menu. Upon the PC booting up again, the icon should in fact not have moved, and remain where you left it on the desktop.

If you have ever logged into a domain, and then logged out again, and read what Windows said it was doing, one of the things Windows said it did was "saving your personal preferences" (or 'settings' or something similar - I only know what it says in Danish: "Gemmer dine personlige indstillinger"). If it is unexpectedly shut down (as it is by a BSOD), it won't save these personal settings.

The Geek-site "How-To Geek" has a great article explaining BSOD's, why they occur, how to troubleshoot them (should you wish to), etc. - you can find it here: http://www.howtogeek.com/163452/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-blue-screen-of-death/ (at least I find it to be great).